# is there a method to SelfUpdate a console application in MSVSC C# .net5

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm develop a simple Console Application c# (GT-AutoPatcher.exe) with MSVSC2022 .NET5 capable of update some files in windows systems, include itselfs. The problem is, when i try to update the "updater" (the created app called GT-AutoPatcher.exe) i get stucked because i dont know the correct way to update a running program...

**I'm trying this**

```
using (WebClient web1 = new WebClient()) {
            web1.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Other");
            web1.DownloadFile("http://*/","GT-AutoPatcher.exe"); 
 }
```

**But result is:**

```
Unhandled exception. System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\*\bin\Debug\net5.0\GT-AutoPatcher.exe' because it is being used by another process.
```

**Reasons:**
The console application is running. How can i close it to donwload a new version?

Comment: One way you can do is install the new version to its own folder and update all shortcut and all and next time new version starts, cleanup old files.

Comment: Unfortunately its a Single File App (GT-AutoPatcher.exe).

Comment: In that case you can download and store new version of the executable as `Latest-GT-AutoPatcher.exe` and then when old running executable exists, before exiting, check if such a file exists in working directory, then invoke a bat or powershell script to rename it to original file copying over current one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close the program, you can refer to this code:

```
public static class Program1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CloseApp("your file type");//Change this to what you want to turn off
        }
        private static void CloseApp(string ArrayProcessName)
        {
            string[] processName = ArrayProcessName.Split(',');
            foreach (string appName in processName)
            {
                Process[] localByNameApp = Process.GetProcessesByName(appName);//Get all processes with program name
                if (localByNameApp.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var app in localByNameApp)
                    {
                        if (!app.HasExited && app.MainWindowTitle == "your file name")
                        {
                            app.Kill();//close the process
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```